# Acessing specific key/values in nested array in each iteration

Tags: php

I am only interested in keys `class` and `score` and their values in my nested array. How can I only get these keys values to be printed out?

This is my `$result` array.

```
{  "images": [    {      "classifiers": [        {          "classifier_id": "default",          "name": "default",          "classes": [            {              "class": "banana",              "score": 0.562,              "type_hierarchy": "/fruit/banana"            },            {              "class": "fruit",              "score": 0.788            },            {              "class": "diet (food)",              "score": 0.528,              "type_hierarchy": "/food/diet (food)"            },            {              "class": "food",              "score": 0.528            },            {              "class": "honeydew",              "score": 0.5,              "type_hierarchy": "/fruit/melon/honeydew"            },            {              "class": "melon",              "score": 0.501            },            {              "class": "olive color",              "score": 0.973            },            {              "class": "lemon yellow color",              "score": 0.789            }          ]        }      ],      "image": "fruitbowl.jpg"    }  ],  "images_processed": 1,  "custom_classes": 0}
```

And this is my code logic.

```
foreach($result as $imgage => $classifier)
{
    foreach($classifier["classes"] as $clas)
    {
        foreach($clas as $key => $value)
        {
            echo $key . ": " . $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how about `if ($key == "class" || $key == "score") echo $key . ": " . $value;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you,

```
<?php
$string = '{"images":[{"classifiers":[{"classifier_id":"default","name":"default","classes":[{"class":"banana","score":0.562,"type_hierarchy":"/fruit/banana"},{"class":"fruit","score":0.788},{"class":"diet (food)","score":0.528,"type_hierarchy":"/food/diet (food)"},{"class":"food","score":0.528},{"class":"honeydew","score":0.5,"type_hierarchy":"/fruit/melon/honeydew"},{"class":"melon","score":0.501},{"class":"olive color","score":0.973},{"class":"lemon yellow color","score":0.789}]}],"image":"fruitbowl.jpg"}],"images_processed":1,"custom_classes":0}';
$array = json_decode($string,1);
foreach($array['images'] as $key => $images)
{
        foreach($images['classifiers'] as $key => $classes)
        {
            foreach($classes['classes'] as $cls_score){
                echo "class = ". $cls_score['class'].  " & score = ". $cls_score['score'].PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
}
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/vF2RL

Answer (score 1):

Can you try ?

```
$str = '{  "images": ....  }'; 

// get associative array from json
$result = json_decode($str, true)['images'];
foreach ($result as $imgage => $classifiers) {
    foreach ($classifiers["classifiers"] as $classifier) {
        foreach ($classifier["classes"] as $clas) {
            foreach ($clas as $key => $value) {
                // you can add condition here to target only desired keys
                echo $key . ": " . $value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```